# Why did my keyboard's volume keys stop working with Mac OS 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded my Mac to 10.8 yesterday when it was released and the update has caused my MacBook's volume keys to become non-functional, although I can still change volume through the icon in the menu bar or through system preferences. When I press the keys to change the volume, the transparent volume icon appears on the screen with a circle-slash icon at bottom center. Does anyone know how to make the keys functional again?

Comment: Which audio adapter is selected in your system preferences, or when you hold `Option` and press the volume icon in the menubar?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "audio adapter". The output device is set correctly to internal speakers.

Comment: i am also encountering this same thing.

Comment: For future reference, it's likely that restarting just `coreaudiod` instead of your Mac might help. Try `sudo killall coreaudiod`

Answer (score 0):

The "circle-slash" means that it's muted. Do you have a mute key on your keyboard that you can press to toggle mute, or can you manually unmute it in settings?

Comment: It's not muted. When I press the mute key, the effect is almost the same as with the volume adjustment keys, the only difference being that the transparent speaker icon has a slash through it, indicating mute (although the key does not mute or unmute the sound). That mute icon has the same white circle-slash at bottom center as the volume adjustment icon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself after I rebooted.