# OSX 10.8 play/pause, and next/prev media keys no longer work

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

Last week I upgraded to OSX 10.8 and some of the media keys on my keyboard have stopped working. I have an Adesso MKB-135B which I have been happily using for over a year. After the upgrade only the mute and volume up/down media keys are working. The play/pause and next/previous buttons are completely non-functional. Even focusing directly on the iTunes app has no effect.

I searched and found a similar problem here: [Why did my keyboard's volume keys stop working with Mac OS 10.8 Mountain Lion?](https://superuser.com/q/454026/149646)

But a reboot did not solve my issue.

Any ideas out there on what I can try?

Comment: I am also having the same problem with my mac mini after installing mountain lion. This problem seems to be affecting iTunes and Quicktime only because media keys work fine with VLC and PandoraJam. Did you try using the media keys with other apps?

Comment: I've contacted my keyboard manufacturer, Adesso, and they told me my keyboard is a discontinued model and there is no support for it to work on 10.8. Really sucks because its an expensive mechanical keyboard...